# Python3 OpenWeather API using sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket, openweathermap

is there a easy way to get the same output importing only "sockets"
as these 3 lines of code using urllib:

```
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}&units=metric'.format(city, api_key)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
weather_decoded = uh.read().decode()
```

where city is for example London and the api_key is your key(you can run in in your terminal with: curl "the url" so you can see the output json file

weather_decoded now holds the json file with the current information about the city

Is there a easy/smart way doing the same thing using "import socket" instead of importing urrlib

What I have so far is this:

import socket

```
server = 'api.openweathermap.org'
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=b498767252de12f92504d2cca9c3fdc1'
port = 80

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + url + "\n\n"
request_bytes = str.encode(request)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((server, port))
    s.sendall(request_bytes)
    data = s.recv(4096)

print(repr(data))
```

But this just returns that I use a bad request, which I obviously do, but most of the requests I found are so far look just like mine.

The output I get:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: openresty\r\nDate: Fri, 08 Feb 2019 18:48:58 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 166\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

The output I am looking for(A json file from the url):

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":282.45,"pressure":993,"humidity":87,"temp_min":281.15,"temp_max":283.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":230},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1549650000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1414,"message":0.0039,"country":"GB","sunrise":1549610791,"sunset":1549645418},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @grooveplex Hey, well sort of, the HW should be the code above, just want to know how that code actually works. This is what i got(And some wariations of it, just does not seem to work at all) https://codeshare.io/2KdAMz

Comment: @DennisVymer: I recommend that you include what you've tried so far to the question and also explain what you expect and why you expect it and what you get instead. Some hints: the basic idea is correct but the HTTP request expects only the path and not the full URL, the line ending is slightly wrong and you do an implicit connection keep-alive due to HTTP/1.1 which might cause the code to hang until the server closes the connection. And of course, to get to the JSON body you have to actually strip the header from the response.  It might be helpful if you make yourself more familiar with HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So in the request I could just write: Get /data/2.5 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: weather?q=London.....\r\n\n something like that, like dont write the full url, just the data_path and the data_name ? Just trying to ask since I am curious. And I did claryfi, what I have and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=b498767252de12f92504d2cca9c3fdc1'
port = 80

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + url + "\n\n"
```

The HTTP request should contain the path after GET and the domain at the Host header. This means the request should look like this:

```
GET /data/2.5/weather?q=London,... HTTP/1.1
Host: api.openweathermap.org
```

Apart from that the line end should be `\r\n` not `\n` although this specific server does not care. And, you better use `HTTP/1.0` instead of `HTTP/1.1` so that you don't have to deal with connection keep-alive and chunked responses, although this specific server currently does not use this either.

Comment: awesome thanks! Now the request actually makes sense.